# d2i_ECParameters Returns Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, openssl

I want to create a EC_Key from NSData, via OpenSSL. So I write the following:

```
- (void)setPrivateKey:(NSData *)privateKey {
      const unsigned char *bits = (unsigned char *) [privateKey bytes];
      eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
      ec_group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
      EC_KEY_set_group(eckey, ec_group);
      EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey);
      EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(eckey, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);
      eckey = d2i_ECParameters(&eckey, &bits, privateKey.length);
}
```

but

```
eckey = d2i_ECParameters(&eckey, &bits, privateKey.length);
```

returns null.

What is the problem?

Comment: What does `ERR_get_error` return after the call to `d2i_ECParameters` fails?

Comment: @jww It doesn't generate proper error code. it generates `218570875`. I found that is errors on `d2i_ECPKParameters(&ret->group, in, len)` in `d2i_ECParameters` function. but I can't continue to find exact problem

Comment: `218570875` is `0xD07207B`. `openssl errstr 0xD07207B` returns `error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long`. it sounds like the parameters are wrong for `d2i_ECParameters`. EC parameters are domain parameters. Maybe you should use a curve rather than a key. Maybe something like `d2i_ECParameters(&ec_group, &bits, privateKey.length)` instead??

Comment: Also have a look at [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography)on the OpenSSL wiki. It looks like they call two functions to create an EC key: `EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name` and `EC_KEY_generate_key`. If you point is encoded int the `NSData`, then you probably need to create the point and then call `EC_POINT_set_affine_coordinates_GFp`.

Comment: thanks @jww, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jww for his great comments, finally, I succeed to solve this problem by the following code block

```
- (void)setPrivateKey:(NSData *)privateKey {
      const unsigned char *privateKeyBits = (unsigned char *) [privateKey bytes];

     ec_group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
     eckey = EC_KEY_new();
     EC_KEY_set_group(eckey, ec_group);
     EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey);
     EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(eckey, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);

     BIGNUM *prv = BN_bin2bn(privateKeyBits, sizeof(privateKeyBits), NULL);
     EC_KEY_set_private_key(eckey, prv);

     EC_POINT *pub = EC_POINT_new(ec_group);
     EC_POINT_mul(ec_group, pub, prv, NULL, NULL, NULL);
     EC_KEY_set_public_key(eckey, pub);

     pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
     EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY(pkey, eckey);
}
```

Although I had both public key and private key, but with above code I calculated the public key from private key.